# C program to find maximum between two numbers using switch case

Tags: c

```
/* C program to find maximum between two numbers using switch case */

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int m, n;
    printf("\nEnter the first number\n");
    scanf("\n%d", &m);
    printf("\nEnter the second number\n");
    scanf("\n%d", &n);

    switch (m > n) { /* it will give result either as 0 or 1*/
      case 0:
        printf("\nThe greater number is %d\n", n);
        break;
      case 1:
        printf("\nThe greater number is %d\n", m);
        break;
      default:
        printf("\nBoth number's are same\n");
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error stating that `switch` condition has a Boolean value.

Kindly help me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? As my 4.8.4 gives no errors.

Comment: MSVC gives a warning. A value does not need to be `1` to be `true`. `0` is false and all other values are `true`. You cannot safely assume that `true` is `1`. For example `int apples = 5; if(apples) { };` evaluates to `true` and plainly is not `1`.

Comment: _printf("\nThe greater number is %d\n",n);_ This is a false statement if they are equal. Anyway chose the right tool for the job - in this case it would be an if statement

Comment: You're using `switch` for the purpose `if` exists.  You're assuming a boolean condition is represented as 0 or 1, that's up to the implementation.   And I suspect what you're seeing is actually a warning, not an "error".  And the whole switch is nonsense.  Consider what happens if both `m` and `n` are, say, 1.  `m > n` is false, hence 0, output *The greater number is 1*.  (There is no 3rd result of a boolean expression.)  Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: A value does not have to be 1 to be true, but in C the relational operators always return 0 or 1.

Comment: @SandeepGhemire: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m > n` is somewhat unusual control expression for `switch`. The allowed values are either `1` (when `m > n`) or `0` (when `m <= n`). The warning is issued, because you defined superfluous `default` label, which is considered out of range.

The `-Wswitch-bool` warning is described in [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wswitch-bool-412) (emhasis mine):

> Warn whenever a `switch` statement has an index of boolean type and the
>   case values are **outside the range of a boolean type**. It is possible to
>   suppress this warning by casting the controlling expression to a type
>   other than bool.

To cover all three cases, you may use different compare expression:

```
switch ((m > n) - (m < n)) {
    case -1: // m < n
    case  1: // m > n
    case  0: // m == n
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of problem you should just if-statements for, but if you're set on using switch cases: Your check can only tell you if your variable m is larger than n, not if they're equal. `switch ((m > n) + (m >=n))` will give you 2 if m is larger, 1 if they're equal and 0 if n is larger.